# Add a percent chance of something happening in R

Tags: r, statistics, percentage

I have a vector of numbers stored in R.

```
my_vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to add two to each number.

```
my_vector + 2
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

However, I want there to only be a twenty percent chance of adding two to the numbers in my vector each time I run the code. Is there a way to code this in R?

What I mean is, if I run the code, the output could be:
    [1] 3 4 5 6 9

Or perhaps

```
[1] 5 4 5 6 7
```

i.e. there is only a 20% chance that any one number in the vector will get two added to it.

Comment: `my_vector+2` is ? Please post the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myvector + 2*sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), length(myvector), prob=c(0.2,0.8), repl=TRUE)
```

That will give a variable number of 2's to be added (which is what you were asking) but sometimes people want to know that exactly 20% will have a 2 added in whoch case it would be:

```
myvector + 2*sample(c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,4)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the check. Fixed.

Comment: You can also try `my_vector+2*(runif(length(my_vector))<0.2)`

Comment: Fixed the error in the length of the prob arg, too.